# documentPath is not a valid resource path when deployed to Google App Engine with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

**Description:**
I have a frontend React client that is hosted on Firebase Hosting and a NodeJS Express API that is hosted on Google App Engine. The client needs to send a POST request to a NodeJS Express route, the request need to contain a variable called *formid* that holds the name of a firebase document. When both the server and client is run locally the *formid* variable gets sent to the API and it is not empty or undefined. But when the API is deployed and the request is sent to GAE instead I get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
```

The error appears in the Google Cloud Platform Console. In left hand menu I go to; Operations > Logging > Logs Viewer. But I can also tail the logs to my local console with the command "gcloud app logs tail -s default".

**Question:** Why does the error appear only when the request is sent to GAE and not when I run them locally?

request.headers.form_id contains the name of the document stored in a collection (which is an autoID) in Google Firestore.

```js
async function postFormQuestionHandler(request, response) {
    let form_ref = db.collection("forms").doc(request.headers.form_id);

    ... other code
```

Express router that recieves the request, forwards it to postFormQuestionHandler function.

```js
router.post("/question", (req, res) => {
    postFormQuestionHandler(req, res);
});
```

Here is where the request firstly is being sent:

```js
async addQuestionsToFormDb(idToken, fomrid, questionids) {
    let result = await questionids.map(async (questionid) => {
        let data = {
            idToken: idToken,
            form_id: formid,
            question_id: questionid,
        };
        
        return await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/form/question`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: data
        });
}
```

From above code I have also tried using the Axios library but it also produces the same error on when the API is deployed to GAE. I have tried reading the documentation of both **Axios** ([Github Axios Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)) and **Fetch** ([Firefox MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) but it have not helped me, am I missunderstanding something? Below is what I tried with Axios:

```js
return await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/form/question`, {}, {
        headers: data,
    }
);
```

**Other information**
Im using Express **v4.17.1** and Node **v10.19.0**, I am also developing this with WSL 2 on Windows 10 2004.

Comment: did you get this error on client or server?

Comment: @ducmai Oh forgot to mention that, will edit that in! But I got it in Google Cloud Platform Console > Operations > Logging > Logs viewer. But I could also tail them to my local console with "gcloud app logs tail -s -default".

Comment: are you sure that process.env.REACT_APP_API is having correct setting?

Comment: @ducmai Yes I think so, I have one file named .env.production which have REACT_APP_API variable only and the address to the API, and another filed named .env.development which has the same named variable only but has value of http://localhost:5000 instead

Answer (score 0):

your `request.headers.form_id` is either empty string or contain invalid character. I guess it contains slash `/`. Here is more info https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields